# Illustrator: Way to align / justify text with left + right in the same text box?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, alignment, typesetting, paragraph-styles

Is there a way to align / justify text with left + right in the same text box, without creating a new text box? It's not too big of a deal, but would save time, if there is a workaround.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Each paragraph in the same text box can have different text alignments, so you cannot set more than 1 text alignment per paragraph.

Comment: Aw, sad day. Thanks for the reply!

Adobe, let's fix this!

Comment: @JaceInman why is that a problem? You don't need to make a new text box, just hit return and start a new paragraph! Multiple alignments in a single paragraph doesn't even make sense without newlines, so just have a paragraph with no bottom spacing.